# I am receiving error when I click on first list items to get array list that is teacherNames field in the same matching course that is selected

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase, web

I have a courses collection  and then I have three separate entries for courses, then I have name and array of teachers fields.

[check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1chL.png)

I have two  drop downs containing list of courses from name fields  and on clicking any courses, we should get list of teachers from the array that matches the course field.

I am getting dropdown 1 of courses but on clicking any course, following error display. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br67y.png)

here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Course {
    String name;

Course({required this.name});

     factory Course.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
     return Course(name: map['name']);
    }
}

class Teacher {
String name;

Teacher({required this.name});

  factory Teacher.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Teacher(name: map['name']);
   }
 }

class CourseSelectionScreen extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_CourseSelectionScreenState createState() => _CourseSelectionScreenState();
 }

  class _CourseSelectionScreenState extends State<CourseSelectionScreen> {
   final CollectionReference coursesCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('courses');
  final CollectionReference teachersCollection =
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('teachers');

Course? selectedCourse;
List<String> teacherNames = [];

    @override
   void initState() {
       super.initState();
 }

   Future<void> fetchTeacherNames() async {
      if (selectedCourse != null) {
        QuerySnapshot snapshot = await teachersCollection
            .where('course', isEqualTo: selectedCourse!.name)
            .get();

        setState(() {
            teacherNames = snapshot.docs
                .map((doc) => Teacher.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>).name)
                .toList();
        });
    }
    }

    Future<List<Course>> fetchCourses() async {
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await coursesCollection.get();
      return snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Course.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
  }

     Future<void> handleCourseSelection(Course? course) async {
    setState(() {
        selectedCourse = course;
    });

    await fetchTeacherNames();
    }

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Course Selection'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                    Text(
                        'Choose a Course:',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    FutureBuilder<List<Course>>(
                        future: fetchCourses(),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return CircularProgressIndicator();
                            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                List<Course> courses = snapshot.data!;
                                return DropdownButton<Course>(
                                    value: selectedCourse,
                                    onChanged: (Course? course) {
                                        handleCourseSelection(course);
                                    },
                                    items: courses.map((course) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem<Course>(
                                            value: course,
                                            child: Text(course.name),
                                        );
                                    }).toList(),
                                );
                            } else {
                                return Text('No courses available');
                            }
                        },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 16),
                    if (selectedCourse != null)
                        Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                                Text(
                                    'Teachers:',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                                DropdownButton<String>(
                                    value: null,
                                    onChanged: null,
                                    items: teacherNames.map((name) {
                                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                            value: name,
                                            child: Text(name),
                                        );
                                    }).toList(),
                                ),
                               ],
                           ),
                   ],
               ),
           ),
       );
   }
}

 void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
```

}

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
           home: CourseSelectionScreen(),
        );
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error?